# React stateless example

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I just started learning React and here's the first state example that I am working on.

Here's the code :-

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script>        

    //main render
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(TextAreaCounter, {text: 'Bob'}),
        document.getElementById("app")
    );

    //create component now
    var TextAreaCounter = React.createClass({

        propTypes: {
            text: React.propTypes.string,
        },  

        getDefaultProps: function() {
            return {
                text: '',
            };
        },

        render: function(){
            return React.DOM.div(null,
                React.DOM.textarea({
                    defaultValue: this.props.text,
                }),
                React.DOM.h3(null, this.props.text.length)
            );
        }           

    });

</script>
```

Here's the error in console:

```
react.js:20150 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
    at invariant (react.js:20150)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (react.js:18327)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (react.js:6256)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (react.js:6139)
    at Object.mountComponent (react.js:13787)
    at mountComponentIntoNode (react.js:11873)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (react.js:16987)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (react.js:11895)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (react.js:16987)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (react.js:10324)
```

What wrong am I doing here? I tried to find some solutions googling the error I received in console, but nothing helped me. Would be great to get some expert comment on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, You need to define the `TextAreaCounter` first then use `ReactDOM.render` to render the `TextAreaCounter` component.

**Reason** will be, at the time of rendering `TextAreaCounter` in `ReactDOM.render` value of `TextAreaCounter` will be `undefined`, If you define that variable as `let` instead of `var` it should throw the error:

> `TextAreaCounter` is not defined.

Just because of `var`, you are not getting that error, I will suggest to read the difference between **`let` and `var`** also. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable).

Write it like this, it will work, run this snippet:

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script >

     var TextAreaCounter = React.createClass({

          getDefaultProps: function() {
              return {
                  text: '',
              };
          },

          render: function() {
              return React.DOM.div(null,
                 React.DOM.textarea({
                    defaultValue: this.props.text,
                 }),
                 React.DOM.h3(null, this.props.text.length)
              );
          }
     });

     ReactDOM.render(
          React.createElement(TextAreaCounter, {text: 'Bob'}),
          document.getElementById("app")
     );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just learning React I recommend you learn JSX which is much easier to understand. In that case your code would be

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
        var TextAreaCounter = React.createClass({
            getDefaultProps: function() {
               return {
                   text: '',
               };
             },
             render: function() {
                return (
                  <div>
                   <textarea defaultValue={this.props.text}></textarea>
                   <h3>{this.props.text.length}</h3>
                 </div>
                );
             }
        });
          ReactDOM.render(
            <TextAreaCounter text='Bob' /> ,document.getElementById("app")
        );
        </script>
```

try this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-react-jsx/